# How to interpret backtrace produced by stackshot into a readable format?

Tags: c++, macos, debugging, backtrace

I've started using Stackshot utility in order to debug my executable and got the log below. The command i used is : sudo /usr/libexec/stackshot -i -p [pid]

However, I don't see an easy way to interpret the function backtrace into a readable format of function_name / line_number (similar to the equivalent command in lldb/gdb).

```
Thread ID: 0x130
Thread state: 0x9 == TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT
Thread priority: 0x52/0x52
Thread wait_event: 0xffffff8026cd77a8
Kernel Stack:
Return                  Frame
0xffffff80002d8452        0xffffff80005e3e45
  0xffffff800023695b        0xffffff80005e4072
    0xffffff8000235d5c        0xffffff800042f6e4
      0xffffff800022d18e        0xffffff80002d7607
        0xffffff80005e3e45        0x00000008feedface
          0xffffff80005e4072        0x00000000ffffff80
            0xffffff800042f6e4        0x0000000000000000
              0xffffff80002d7607        0x0000000900000000
```

Comment: Did you find  a way to analyse stackshots?